# Where does STM32CubeMX generate AF GPIO initialization?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, hal-library

i was wondering where does CubeMX (when you export it to an IDE such as Atollic) generate GPIO initialization for alternate functions such as Timer capture pins, UART pin ect. (we are talking about HAL drivers) I've noticed it's not initialized in GPIO_Init nor the specific  initialization function used. I want to set pull up on an AF pin without having to import the project again. So where is it?

Comment: You can configure CubeMX to generate code for Atollic Truestrudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind i'm blind, it's in stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c file.